# Recording web scraping data

Tags: python

Hi everyone although I got the data I was looking for in a text format, when I try to record it as a list or convert it into a dataframe, it simply doesn't work. What I got was a huge list with only one item, which is the last text line of the data I got, i.e. the number '9.054.333,18'. Can anyone help me, please? I need to organize all this data in a list or dataframe.

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

html = urlopen('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/market-data-e-indices/servicos-de-dados/market-data/consultas/mercado-a-vista/termo/posicoes-em-aberto/posicoes-em-aberto-8AA8D0CC77D179750177DF167F150965.htm?data=16/04/2021&f=0#conteudo-principal')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

texto = soup.find_all('td')
for t in texto:
    print(t.text)

lista=[]

for i in soup.find_all('td'):
   lista.append(t.text)

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iterators are wrong -- you're using `i` in the last loop while appending `t.text`.

You can just use a list comprehension:

```
# ...

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

lista = [t.text for t in soup.find_all('td')]
```